# Работа со строками в Си

Tags: c, массивы, строки, проверка

Моя проблема состоит в том, что результат данной программы вывод строки :"yours love yourslla".А нужно чтобы результатом было : "yours love wella". Т.е. нужно осуществить проверку на разделители,чтобы заменялось только полноценное слово. Если кто знает как это осуществить, подскажите,пожалуйста.

```
void Replace(char str[], char slovo1[], char slovo2[], char buffer[])
{
    int i, j, pos = 0;
    for(i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; str[i + j] && slovo1[j]; j++)   //начинается ли с i-ой позиции строка slovo1
            if(str[i + j] != slovo1[j])
                break;
        if(!slovo1[j])  
        {
            i += j - 1;  //в j у нас длина стоки slovo1, которую мы перепрыгиваем
            for(j = 0; slovo2[j]; j++)
                buffer[pos++] = slovo2[j];  //на место стоки slovo1 ставим строку slovo2
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[pos++] = str[i];   //просто копируем символ
        }
        buffer[pos] = NULL;  //ставим конец строки
    }
    strcpy(str, buffer);  //копируем в первоначальную строку
}

int main()
{
    char str[100] = "we love wella";
    char slovo1[] = "we", slovo2[] = "yours";
    char buffer[200];
    Replace(str, slovo1, slovo2, buffer);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что за массив `a`?

Comment: Вот решение вашей задачи https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-replace-word-text-another-given-word/

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup, исправила

Comment: @becouse, там так же заменяют не только слово но и его часть, или я не так поняла?

Comment: Только слово. Совпадение со словом. Вы протестируйте.

Comment: @becouse, извините, что так много вопросов, но не могу понять, вы про 2 способ говорите? Я потестила первый и он так же выводит "yours love yourslla", а второй на си и пока не могу понять, что он выводит

Comment: У вас в задаче написано "нужно осуществить проверку на разделители,чтобы заменялось только полноценное слово". Это можно понять только как "заменить слово полностью".

Comment: @because полноценное слово, в моем объяснении, это we, а wella-это we в составе другого слова и оно не должно никак меняться . А проверка на разделители это проверка, что перед и после we стоят разделители, а не буквы. И есть это полноценное слово, то менять, а если после или перед стоят буквы, то ничего не менять

Comment: Вот совсем ваш случай https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160073/replacing-words-inside-string-in-c